# Two forms in one view with some common attributes Validation error Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two forms in my view but the model is the same for both forms. In the first form i skipped one model field `ShopAddress` so that is [Required] field but this field has no need in first form so when i submit the form i had got validation error. In second form same way i don't want `UserName` Field that is also [required] field. so on submit form also getting validation error any solution?. i hope so you understand my question Thanks:)

**Model**

```
public partial class User
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="The Name field is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Your Name")]
    [MaxLength(50 , ErrorMessage = "Name Cannot Be Longer Than 50 Characters")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z \s]+$", ErrorMessage = "Input Allows Only Alphabets")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    [MinLength(4, ErrorMessage = "Input Allows Minimum 4 Characters")]
    [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "User Name Cannot Be Longer Than 10 Characters")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "User Name Does Not Contain Space and Special Characters.")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Email Cannot Be Longer Than 50 Characters")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z-._0-9]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.[A-Za-z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ShopAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Phone")]
    [MaxLength(11, ErrorMessage = "Please Enter a Valid Phone Number")]
    [MinLength(11, ErrorMessage = "Please Enter a Valid Phone Number ")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Input Allows Only Numbers")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Password Cannot Be Longer Than 30 Characters")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Confirm Password Does'nt Match With Password")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(User user)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
       //add in db          
  }
  return view()
}
```

**View**

```
@model RentalServices.Models.User
                <div class="hideSingleUserForm">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-11">
                            @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
                            {
                                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" })
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter Your Name" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" })
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter User Name" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" })
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter Your Valid Phone Number" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" })
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter Your Valid Email Address" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" })
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter Your Password" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" })
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Confirm Password" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <div class="">
                                        <button type="submit" class="roundSubmitBtn margin-top-20">CREATE ACCOUNT</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="hideBusinessForm" style="display:none">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-11">
                            **Second Form**
                            @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = "ShopForm" }))

                                {
                                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Shop Name</label>
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "1", placeholder = "Enter Your Name" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">

                                            <label>Shop Address</label>
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ShopAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "2", placeholder = "Enter User Name" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ShopAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" })
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "3", placeholder = "Enter Your Valid Phone Number" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" })
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "4", placeholder = "Enter Your Valid Email Address" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" })
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "5", placeholder = "Enter Your Password" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" })
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "6", placeholder = "Confirm Password" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <div class="">
                                        <button type="submit" class="roundSubmitBtn margin-top-20" id="SubmitShopForm">CREATE ACCOUNT</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your underlying model may be similar, but this is a useful case for creating a viewmodel: a representation of the data model specific to the view that is using it. That way you can enforce the required state separately and handle mapping back to your data model in the controller.